# Is there a way to change the Bluemix user interface back to dark colours?

Tags: user-interface, interface, ibm-cloud, dashboard

Just restarted Bluemix and the dashboard interface is now all white, days prior it was darkish green /blue , is there a way to go back to the dark colours

Answer (score 1):

There was a replacement of the Bluemix "classic" console for the public regions deployed on 10/20/16. This is now the default console and the dark theme is no longer available.

Here is an excerpt from the Bluemix Status Page:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/status/

> Announcement: Replacement of the Bluemix "classic" console for
>   the public regions
>
> As you have logged into the Bluemix console over
>   the last few months, you have likely noticed a link in the upper-left
>   corner of our user interface banner that has invited you to "Try the
>   new Bluemix." This link has redirected you to a new console with an
>   updated design. As of Thursday, October 20th, our new console will
>   become the default user interface for the public regions and the
>   "classic" console will not be available. The new console provides the
>   following enhancements over the existing "classic" console:
>
> - Improved classification of our services and runtimes
> - Direct access to the services that you are currently using
> - Links to popular tasks
>
> As we
>   continue to enhance our Bluemix platform, we welcome ideas that will
>   make your experience even better. For information on submitting
>   "structured ideas," see [Think, write, submit: New ideas portal for
>   IBM Cloud](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2016/10/05/think-write-submit/).

Comment: Thanks, Cheers, Merci